# Customize startup

Tags: version-8, customization

Is there a way to personalize the startup?
I want, for example, that mathematica starts Maximized (not slightly-less-than-maximized as it usually does) with a notebook (also maximized) with a zoom of 130%.
I use mathematica 8.0.4 and windows XP.

Comment: Do you mean you want the new notebook to open in full-screen, or just as a maximized window? I think I know how to launch in real full screen mode on Mac OS X, but it involves Applescript, so it's platform dependent. What is your platform?

Comment: @Jens No need for applescript... `SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[],WindowSize -> Full]` does it :)

Comment: @R.M. Thanks - that's better. I just thought of scripting because I have one notebook that I always launch via Applescript, so I would have re-used that approach...

Answer (score 4):

In MMA prefs / advanced/ open option inspector and you can set the values you want to customize.  Full screen is under Window Size and select "Full".  Zoom is under Notebook Options/ Display options/ Magnification.

Comment: Selecting "Full" under Notebook Options/Windows properties/Windows size does nothing but the magnification worked well.

Comment: F12 or cmd/option/F will also give you full screen.

Answer (score 4):

I find it easiest to create a Notebook with the features I want, and then open that Notebook to launch *Mathematica*.

Save this code as a `.nb` file.  If you want *Mathematica* to also open "Maximized" rather than in the slightly-less-than-Maximized form it usually does, also create a shortcut to this Notebook and change the properties to Maximized, then use that.

```
Notebook[{},
  Saveable->False,
  WindowSize->Scaled[1],
  WindowMargins->{{Automatic, 0}, {Automatic, 0}},
  Magnification->1.3,
]
```

Comment: If you tried the version with `Editable->False` and of course it failed, please try now.

Comment: why `Saveable -> False`? Or is this your invisble notebook/

Comment: @R.M `Saveable -> False` so that you do not accidentally overwrite this starting Notebook and have to create it again.  *Mathematica* should still prompt you to save the file on closing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Mathematica doesn't prompt me to do save the file on closing but when i open this notebook, it is in fullscreen mode and with the right magnification,as desired and what do you exactly mean with "change the properties to maximized".

Comment: @Mr. Wizard in fact, the documentation says: `A notebook with the option setting Saveable->False can always be saved using the Save As menu item, but does not respond to Save and does not prompt for saving when it is closed.`

Comment: @Diego Indeed.  I admit I didn't try this before posting (and made at least one careless error as a result) but I was sure I'd had the behavior previously of closing a notebook and being prompted to save, just as you get with Notebooks created with `File > New > Notebook` Either I misremember or there is another setting I'm forgetting.

Comment: Given that the current answer may have dangerous side effects I suggest you delete it until you have sorted this out.

Comment: What's dangerous about this? If the comments are outdated they should be deleted, they are puzzling/confusing/perplexing/flummoxing

Answer (score 0):

You could either edit the `Default.nb` notebook to fit your needs, or inherit from it to create another stylesheet, and set it as the default by changing `$FrontEnd`'s `DefaultStyleDefinition`'s option to that new notebook.